# Rails cancan not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, cancan

I am trying to build a blog where there will be 2 users admin and normal user.Admin can view every post and comment .Whereas normal user can view his only post and comment .I have applied my logic but it is not working  .In my code every user can  view each other post and comment which I don't want .I have uploaded my code at github 
[link](https://github.com/aniketstiwari/photo)

[ability.rb]

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
   def initialize(user)
        unless user
        else
          case user.roles
          when 'admin'
           can :manage, Post
           can :manage, Comment
         when 'user' 
           can :manage, Post, user_id: user.id
           can :manage, Comment, user_id: user.id
         end
        end
```

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user! 
    authorize_resource

    def index
        @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
    end

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        @post.user = current_user

        if @post.save
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])

        if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :body))
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @post.destroy

        redirect_to posts_path
    end

    private

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

[comment_controller]

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
          authorize_resource

    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))
         @comment.user = current_user
         @comment.save
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end

    def destroy
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
        @comment.destroy

        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end
end
```

[user.rb]

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
      has_many :posts
      has_many :comments
end
```

[post.rb]

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
    validates :body,  presence: true
    belongs_to :user
end
```

[comment.rb]

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user

end
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code here.

Comment: please see I have updated with the relevant code

Comment: Thank you.  A couple of questions: 
1. `case user.roles`... shouldn't this be `case user.role` (singular)?
2. Where is your logic that restricts the user's view based on this ability?

Comment: I have written roles as my table column name in users table....should i change it to role???

Comment: Well... it should always read like English.  Does a user have a role?  Or does a user have roles?

Comment: I have applied in ability.rb can :manage, Post, user_id: user.id ..it means if user_id== current_user then only the post will be shown also ....in controller i have written authorize_resource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly...

`CanCan` is no longer maintained; [`CanCanCan`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) should be added to your `Gemfile`:

```
#Gemfile
gem "cancancan"
```

--

You'll be able to use the following:

```
#app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    case user.roles
       when "admin" #-> use double quotes for evaluating strings
          can :manage, [Post, Comment]
       when "user"
          can :manage, [Post, Comment], user_id: user.id
       end
  end
end
```

--

You also need to make sure you're calling `authorize!`.

Although [`authorize_resource`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/CanCan%2FControllerAdditions%2FClassMethods%3Aauthorize_resource) is good, in your case, you need to make sure you're sticking to convention...

```
#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    authorize_resource :post
    authorize_resource :comment

    def create
        @post    = Post.find params[:post_id]
        @comment = @post.comments.new comment_params
        @comment.user = current_user
        @comment.save

        redirect_to @post
    end

    def destroy
        @post    = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.find params[:id]
        @comment.destroy

        redirect_to @post
    end

    private

    def comment_params
       params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :body)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you just need to add :read instruction along with :manage to disallow user to view other users posts.

Like this:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
   def initialize(user)
        unless user
        else
          case user.roles
          when 'admin'
           can :manage, Post
           can :manage, Comment
         when 'user' 
           can :manage, Post, user_id: user.id
           can :manage, Comment, user_id: user.id
           can :read, Post, user_id: user.id
           can :read, Comment, user_id: user.id
       end
     end
  end
end
```

please refer to this page: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities

Answer (score -2):

Hope you have maintain the roles for each users as admin or normal.

you can try this

```
in ability.rb

include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

     case user.role

     when User::Roles::ADMIN
       can :manage, :all
     end

     when User::Roles::USER
       can :create, Comment, :user_id => user.id
     end
  end
```

Hope this will help

Comment: what is user.role and User::Roles::ADMIN ...role and Roles are two different things?

Comment: User is the current object you have passed and it contains a field as role whereas In your User.rb file(model) you can define a module like 'module Roles
    ADMIN: = 'super_admin'  '  the super_admin is the role defined in your User model